# How to activate apache2?

Tags: server, apache2

I installed apache2 as follows on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS machine:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Everythings worked fine here.But after I typed:

```
$ sudo systemctl start apache2
$ sudo systemctl status apache2
```

It showed this:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web serve
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
         └─apache2-systemd.conf
 Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2017-05-16 21:00:45 CST; 16s ago
   Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 5436 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited,status=0/SUCCESS
Process: 5420 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE

May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5420]: (98)Address already in use: AH
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5420]: (98)Address already in use: AH
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5420]: no listening sockets available
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5420]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5420]: Action 'start' failed.
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5420]: The Apache error log may have 
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5420]:  *
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5436]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web s
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB apache2[5436]:  *
May 16 21:00:45 shayuxiong-X555LPB systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Then I just uninstall apache2 and reinstall it,but the situation still occured.
So how can I activate apache2? What does "no listening sockets available" means?
I am totally new to the LAMP installation and this platform.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is using port `80`?

Comment: Run this `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and see who is using port `80`

Comment: @Georage I just followed your advice and I got this:tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1005/nginx.conf

Comment: That means nginx is blocking apache's traditional port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution:

1. Alter the listening port for `nginx server` by opening `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and changing the port or line `listen: 80` to whatever port you like.
2. Reload `nginx server`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart nginx
   ```
3. Now try re-installing apache again.